# Azure KeyVault Get Secret API responds with 404 or 401 error

Tags: rest, azure, azure-keyvault, secret-key

I am trying to get a secret out of Azure Key Vault. It is a very simple Restful API call. For example for all key, it is as simple as this:

```
GET {vaultBaseUrl}/secrets?api-version=7.0
```

where vaultBaseUrl is provided in Azure Console as Vault DNS name.
I am using console mode for testing 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecrets/getsecrets#code-try-0
But the return value if always 404.
When I try curl in the Azure console, it gives 401 - Unauthorized.
However I can use the command line to get the secret out.
Is there any secret to making the restful call and curl work to get the secret out? All these situations use the same credentials.
A side questions is, that on the micorosft api testing page there is a 'Request Preview' section with a green Run button, almost as if it is inviting you to run the api, but the link is to learn.microsoft.com and the copy button on the box is disabled. I have never seen so many problems in one place, so I am thinking may be I don't understand something here.

Answer (score 4):

The doc seems not to be correct. If you want to get the secret, you could use the [Client credentials flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to get the access token and use it to get the secret.

Follow the steps as below.

1.Register an app in the Azure Active Directory, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal). Get the application id and key, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal#get-application-id-and-authentication-key). Add the service principal in the `Access policies` in your keyvault with the correct secret permission(just search the name of your AD App then add it).

2.In the postman, send a request to the url

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/{your tenant id}/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0
```

Request body and complete sample(`client_id` and `client_secret` are the application id and key in step 1):

[image]

3.Copy the `access_token` in step 2, then use it as an Authorization token to call the api:

```
GET https://yourkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets?api-version=7.0
```

[image]

**Besides**, if you want to use CURL to get the secret, try the one like below. The `TOKEN` is the same with the `access_token` in step 2 above.

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer [TOKEN]" https://yourkeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets?api-version=7.0
```

For more details about getting `access_token` via curl and complete steps, you could refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@mauridb/calling-azure-rest-api-via-curl-eb10a06127). Don't forget to change the `resource` to `https://vault.azure.net` in the **Request the Access Token** step.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Bearer token.There will be an Url to  generate a token and pass it to authentication then u will donot get the error.