# Integrate Azure Key Vault with ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, asp.net-4.0

We have asp.net 4.0 application which is now going to deployed to Azure. A look ahead environment with IIS and SQL managed instance has been provided. We have been asked to move the database connection details to Azure Key Vault. Tried searching the internet but got references for mostly .net core applications. Upgrading the .net framework is not an option. So far we have registered an application in Azure Active Directory and got the tenant id, client id, client secret. This application has been added in Access policies with all the permissions. Also the secret key with connection string value has been created. Now the challenge is how to access this key vault secret in our asp.net 4.0 application. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If so, you may not be able to use the SDK directly, you could use C# to get the token, then use the token to call the REST API  - [Get Secret](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/keyvault/getsecret/getsecret).

You could refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860245/azure-keyvault-get-secret-api-responds-with-404-or-401-error/55861950#55861950) for the steps to get the token and call the API, then follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9620278/how-do-i-make-calls-to-a-rest-api-using-c) to do them in C#.

Comment: Thank you Joy, this was helpful. I was able to get the token and get the secrets in Postman. Will follow the link you provided to do it in C#.